# Is it worth upgrading an existing iOS app from Phonegap 1.2 to 1.9?

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, iscroll

The PhoneGap 1.2 app I'm developing has performance issues. I'm currently going over the jQuery code to optimize it as best I can, but I'm wondering how much improvement (if any) I would get by upgrading the project to PhoneGap 1.9. The process of upgrading such an old version is pretty laborious so I'm hoping someone could share their experiences with me.

Using Xcode 4.3.3, Phonegap 1.2, iScroll 4.1.9, and jQuery 1.7.1.

Thanks!

Comment: @ColeJohnson - I can't really post the code because it's a big application and there's not a specific bottleneck. I'm really just asking in the general sense if anyone knows if newer versions of Phonegap are much faster than 1.2

Comment: Yes its worth upgrading... It is hell lot faster....As well as before Phonegap 1.8 , the iOS version of cordova has lots of bugs.

Comment: @Coder_sLaY - great to hear! Can anyone else confirm from their  experience?

Comment: I doubt you will see any huge gain in performance but I am curious to hear how it went. If performance is a big issue you should consider porting it in native obj-c. I have always found phone gap and others a like to be sluggish.

Answer (score 1):

No. And yes

You should upgrade to 2.1 (if you upgrade)

If you don't get any issues and don't want to use more features, you may stay at the version.

If you want to implement new features or create a new version in the store you should update to 2.1

In fact it is a good idea to move to newer versions.

Comment: I upgraded about a month ago to 1.8. I wanted to do 2.0 but the Facebook plugin that we needed only listed compatibility up to 1.8. I tried to do the step listed for upgrading in the phonegap docs, but I found it a lot easier to start a new project from scratch. Most of the plugins needed upgrades and in some cases patches. I didn't actually get any performance increase, but I am now able to login through the Facebook App, which wasn't possible before. Unfortunately I may now have to upgrade to 2.1 because of Phonegap issues with Xcode 4.5 :(